# Complex power properties

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponentiation

A useful property of real numbers is $x^ay^a = (xy)^a$.

(a) Does the property $z^αw^α = (zw)^α$ hold for complex powers?

(b) Does the property $z^αw^α = (zw)^α$ hold for the principal value of a complex power?

How could I prove whether if it applies or not?

Comment: kindly format your question using MathJax

Comment: Complex power is just a shorthand for the Taylor series. You should write out the Taylor series and compare both side, for any specific term.

Comment: What kind of number is $\alpha$?

Comment: I believe α is any given number in the R domain

Comment: @cr001that could be an option

Comment: The way power is often defined is $z^\alpha = \exp(\alpha \log(z))$.  So to be true for any $\alpha$, it reduces to $\log(zw) = \log(z) + \log(w)$.

Comment: point a is undefined since complex powers are sets (the relation is an inclusion of sets in general), point b is partially undefined since principal branch excludes by definition a ray (the standard one is the negative reals) so if $zw$ are on the excluded ray the question is ambiguos (see $z=w=i$ for the standard principal branch) and if $zw$ go "over" the ray, the result is false in general (eg $z=i, w=i-1$ where the sum of the principal arguments goes over $\pi$); usually some type of analytic continuation is needed to have equalities of complex powers and the subject is tricky